# flex box item float right is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div element which contain image background and descriptions,  I want the description to float right inside the image

```css
.about-us {
  &__left {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url('/assets/images/01.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 482px;
  }
  &__leftdescription {
    margin-left: auto;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us">
  <div class="about-us__left">
    <div class="about-us__leftdescription">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Specjalizujemy się w outsourcingu kadry IT;</li>
        <li>Zapewniamy możliwość współpracy ze starannie dobranymi ekspertami IT lub całymi ich zespołami;</li>
        <li>Pracujemy zgodnie z zasadami biznesu Klienta, dbając o wysoki standard świadczonych usług;</li>
        <li>Budujemy i utrzymujemy długotrwałe relacje, oparte na wzajemnym zaufaniu;</li>
        <li>Wartości, jakimi się kierujemy to odwaga, efektywność rozwiązań technicznych, zaangażowanie, zadowolenie Klientów i inwestowanie w kapitał ludzki;</li>
        <li>Jesteśmy elastyczni w dostosowaniu się do technologii, modelu biznesowego oraz kryteriów finansowych naszych Klientów. Ofertę przystosowujemy indywidualnie, aby sprostać szybko zmieniającym się warunkom i trendom rynkowym.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result should look like this: 
[image]

Here is what I have so far
[image]

**NOTE** here is **jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/5c6yfe7s/6/

What am I doing wrong here?  any suggestion help will be apreciated, thanks

Comment: Your structure is wrong and you are applying flexbox to the wrong element - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/g16sejp8/

Comment: your solution is hack sorry :( I didnt check it well I said , text must be inside a background image  what you did is just separating text and image which is wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a `<div>` element, whose parent is using `display:flex`, float to the right, you can add the CSS properties `flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end` to the parent, like the example below:

```css
.about-us__left {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1; 
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-image: url('https://s15.postimg.cc/t22lvakm3/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 482px;
}
.about-us__leftdescription {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us">
  <div class="about-us__left">
    <div class="about-us__leftdescription">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Specjalizujemy się w outsourcingu kadry IT;</li>
        <li>Zapewniamy możliwość współpracy ze starannie dobranymi ekspertami IT lub całymi ich zespołami;</li>
        <li>Pracujemy zgodnie z zasadami biznesu Klienta, dbając o wysoki standard świadczonych usług;</li>
        <li>Budujemy i utrzymujemy długotrwałe relacje, oparte na wzajemnym zaufaniu;</li>
        <li>Wartości, jakimi się kierujemy to odwaga, efektywność rozwiązań technicznych, zaangażowanie, zadowolenie Klientów
          i inwestowanie w kapitał ludzki;</li>
        <li>Jesteśmy elastyczni w dostosowaniu się do technologii, modelu biznesowego oraz kryteriów finansowych naszych Klientów.
          Ofertę przystosowujemy indywidualnie, aby sprostać szybko zmieniającym się warunkom i trendom rynkowym.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But be careful with the structure you used as well as the fixed height, because it doesn't support viewport dimension changes and will not render accordingly when the width is below a certain value!

Comment: Sorry, didn't save the edit before, try this answer!

Comment: Thanks for your solution , much better solution than the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your CSS:

```js
.about-us__left {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('https://s15.postimg.cc/t22lvakm3/image.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  height: 482px;
}
.about-us__leftdescription {
  margin-left: auto;
  flex:0 1 50%; 
}
```

Unfortunately this would look nice **only** on wide screen (1200px)

Comment: Your right there is more css to be applied as you can see even in 1200px stil does not look as expected result, meaning I will add more css to it and find the perfect solution, thanks for helping

Comment: if you change 50% t0 40% your solution is top there.